# Changing footnote marker position

Tags: footnotes, footmisc

I am using `\footmisc` to customize footnotes, but I just can't get the footnote marker where I want it to be(the one that appears at the bottom of the page; not the one in the text, to which I don't want to make any changes).

Let's say the default is:

```
____________
   1. Footnote text
```

What I would like to achieve is something of this sort (notice the space before and after the marker):

```
____________
  1.     Footnote text
```

But I can only get:

```
____________
1.     Footnote text
```

Basically, I can't/don't know how to set space before the footnote marker. The only thing I can indent is the footnote text itself.

Example of what I currently have (played around with other options, but so far this is the closest I've gotten):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{0.5in}
\renewcommand{\hangfootparindent}{0.195in}
\renewcommand{\hangfootparskip}{0\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
Something.\footnote{Here is a footnote.} Something else.\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sitamet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi risus lacus, suscipit vehicula ullamcorper a, tempus consectetur felis.

I set up this indentation for subsequent paragraphs (I'm happy with it.)}
\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And what option(s) are you using for `footmisc`? Please add to your question a simple complete document showing your current settings for footnotes.

Comment: Also, how should footnotes spanning more than one line behave? Where should the second line begin?

Comment: Thank you for replying, Gonzalo. I added an example of what I'm working with.

Comment: The minimal example is useful, but, in this case, it is also important to give some sense of what the correct layout needs to be.  If a footnote contains more than one paragraph, how is the new paragraph set?  Should the '`\parskip`' be zero or should there be whitespace instead?  Are footnotes to be `hang`-ed just not flush with the left margin of the textblock?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `scrextend` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\deffootnote[.5in]{.5in}{.195in}{\makebox[.5in][r]{\thefootnotemark.\hspace{.2in}}}

\begin{document}

Something.\footnote{Here is a footnote.} Something else.\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor
sitamet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi risus lacus, suscipit vehicula ullamcorper a,
tempus consectetur felis.

I set up this indentation for subsequent paragraphs (I'm happy with it.)}
\end{document}
```

It should be clear on what dimensions you have to act for make this suit your taste.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

A redefinition of `\@makefntext` will do the job (the modification is signaled `%NEW` in the example code below). The new length `\margintomarker` lets you control the distance from the margin to the footnote marker; the distance between the marker and the footnote text will be set using `\footnotemargin`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just for the example

\newlength\margintomarker
\setlength\margintomarker{10pt}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{0.5in}
\renewcommand{\hangfootparindent}{0.695in}
\renewcommand{\hangfootparskip}{0\baselineskip}

\makeatletter
\long\def\@makefntext#1{%
\ifFN@hangfoot
\bgroup
\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
\ifdim\footnotemargin>0pt
\hb@xt@\footnotemargin{\@makefnmark\hss}%
\else
\@makefnmark
\fi
}%
\leftmargin\wd\@tempboxa
\addtolength\leftmargin{\margintomarker}% NEW
\rightmargin\z@
\linewidth \columnwidth
\advance \linewidth -\leftmargin
\parshape \@ne \leftmargin \linewidth
\footnotesize
\@setpar{{\@@par}}%
\leavevmode
\llap{\box\@tempboxa}%
\parskip\hangfootparskip\relax
\parindent\hangfootparindent\relax
\else
\parindent1em
\noindent
\ifdim\footnotemargin>\z@
\hb@xt@ \footnotemargin{\hss\@makefnmark}%
\else
\ifdim\footnotemargin=\z@
\llap{\@makefnmark}%
\else
\llap{\hb@xt@ -\footnotemargin{\@makefnmark\hss}}%
\fi
\fi
\fi
\footnotelayout#1%
\ifFN@hangfoot
\par\egroup
\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\null\vfill
\lipsum*[4]Test text\footnote{\lipsum[4]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\null\vfill` commands were just to push the test text to the bottom of the page for the example; they can be safely deleted in your actual document.

Comment: It's easier with KOMA-Script or in the standard classes with the `scrextend` package: `\deffootnote{0.695in}{15pt}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}\hspace{.5in}}`

Comment: it would be good to show this with a second paragraph.  (`lipsum` does paragraph manipulation that makes this not straightforward.  but even with ordinary text, paragraphing results in too big an indent.  i found `\endgraf\quad` to give more attractive results.)

Comment: Thank you Gonzalo. This is exactly what I needed! Now I have a new problem, though. I would like `\thanks` to have the same behavior. Is that possible? (Should I make it a new, separate question?)

Comment: Or any footnote before begin document, apparently (they do not conform to the redefinition of footnote...).

Answer (score 1):

I just added this to my preamble when I faced the same problem:

```
% Space before footnote number (hb@xt@)
% Space between foonote number and text (parindent)
% Adjust to your liking the number before "em"
\makeatletter
\long\def\@makefntext#1{%
    \parindent 1em\noindent\hb@xt@ 4em{\hss\@makefnmark}~#1
}
\makeatother
```

This brief coding was enough to solve the problem.

Comment: Is it an answer... is it a question?

Comment: It is an answer

Comment: It's a little bit ... short ;-)

Comment: Moderators ask us to get to the point :)

Comment: Well, I am no moderator and I did not flag it, but I can not guarantee, that your answer will 'survive' ;-)

Comment: This code solved my problem, but it may not apply to every case, you know.